# EJB restriction: compromise component distributability

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss5.x

It seems that it is forbidden to read files from an EJB as stated in this link:

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/qanda/ejb_tier/restrictions.html#file_access

> Enterprise beans aren't allowed to access files primarily because
>   files are not transactional resources. Allowing EJBs to access files
>   or directories in the filesystem, or to use file descriptors, **would
>   compromise component distributability, and would be a security
>   hazard.**

What does "compromise component distributability" ???

Comment: An interesting discussion on the matter: https://www.coderanch.com/t/161394/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/Why-access-file-system-EJB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from [How to Be Distributable](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_servlets_ch12/index.html?page=2#how2be) from Enterprise Servlets and J2EE:

> An EJB may be distributed across a number of backend machines and may be moved between machines at the container's discretion. To enable this distribution model, EJB must follow a strict specification-defined ruleset for what they can and cannot do.

File system could be different from machine to machine and file descriptors definitely are. Using them could prevent EJB migration and/or passivation.

See also

- [How to access the file system from an EJB 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357667/how-to-access-the-file-system-from-an-ejb-3)
- [Java EE, EJBs File handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286974/java-ee-ejbs-file-handling)